# temporarily save outputs from the r-script in sql?

Tags: r, sql-server, temp-tables

I am running an RScript embedded in a SQL query (MSSQL).

When running the script, I can only ever get one output. Is there some way to temporarily save outputs from the r-script in sql (to use them later again)?

Comment: Is your output a list of tables, or do you just have different version of one table over time?

Comment: @danlooo i have different tables/dfs I wanna save one at a time. Like after one big code chunck has been executed, I would like to save the result of that so that when I continue I dont need to re-run the whole thing.

Comment: Then just separate the R scripts so you can execute them individually